# how can i write a cod with Walrus

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that calculates the sum of the numbers entered by the user. The program will continue until the user has not entered an empty string. (use the walrus operator in the condition).

```
I think all my code is wrong
```

```
summ = []
while (b := int(input('x: '))) != '':
    summ.append(b)

print(sum(summ))
```

Comment: You cannot compare an int with a string

Comment: What @DarkKnight said excepted, your code is ok (though you could directly add the numbers to the total, without storing them in a list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an assignment expression (a.k.a. walrus operator) for your use-case like this:

```
summ = 0

while (b := input('x: ')):
  summ += int(b)

print(summ)
```